# How to add items found while iterating to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Persons> persList = new ArrayList<Persons>();

for(Persons p : persList){
    Persons pers = new Persons();
    pers = service.getPersons(id);
    p.setAddress(pers.getAddress());
    persList.add(pers);
}
```

Is this the right way to add all found Persons to persList? Thank you in advance.

Comment: well,theoreticly,yes, but if you loop on your array to add to your array,you're gonna have a bad time

Comment: The for loop will never run because `persList` is empty to begin with. Did you even run your code?

Comment: you need to loop on service instead

Comment: where's `id` coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you shouldn't modify a list while you're iterating over it, other than via the `Iterator.remove` method. Aside from anything else, even if this code didn't throw an exception, it would go on forever unless `persList` was empty... there's always be new people to iterate over!

You should basically create a new list collecting the items to add, and then use `addAll` at the end:

```
ArrayList<Persons> persList = new ArrayList<Persons>();
// Populate the list, presumably
List<Persons> extraPeople = new ArrayList<Persons>();

for(Persons p : persList){
    // Note: there's no point in creating a new object only to ignore it...
    Persons pers = service.getPersons(id);
    p.setAddress(pers.getAddress());
    extraPeople.add(pers);
}

persList.addAll(extraPeople);
```

This code still doesn't make much sense in my view, as you're fetching via the same `id` value on every iteration... I can only hope this was an example rather than real code.

Also note that if each instance of your `Persons` class is meant to be a single person, it would be better to call it `Person`.

Comment: Considering OP's code I would stress the part where you populate the arrayList before looping over it

Comment: Thanks for you solution and good tips. This is not real code. Just an example.

Comment: @SykWitIt: The problem is, if you present example code which has problems *other than* the one you're actually trying to address, it distracts from the real issue. It's worth taking time to come up with a useful example, in future.